# SQL Server: Date conversion problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column which has date-values stored in varchar (format ddmmyy) like this

```
231280
121280
131185
...
```

How to convert these values into datetime data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set DateFormat DMY
GO
Select Cast(Stuff(Stuff(SomeValue, 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-') As datetime)
From MyData
```

Comment: Using this solution, should I always set dateformat into DMY before execution?

Comment: @jara - Yes because it ensures that Cast interprets the position of month and day correctly independent of the the default date format on the server.

Comment: @jara - Without DateFormat, on a US machine/server for example, it would want to interpret the date as MM-DD-YY instead of DD-MM-YY.

Answer (score 1):

Because this format is non standard, use

```
DECLARE @field char(6)
SET @field = '231280'
select convert(datetime, right(@field, 2) +   substring(@field, 3, 2) + left(@field, 2)  , 12)
```

Comment: The code built the strings in the wrong order causing an error, but the basic idea was right. I fixed the code and tested to make sure it works.

Comment: @JohnFx I edited it 5 seconds after I had posted it. I named my edit, "Doh." Then, 9 minutes later, you did the same :(

Answer (score 1):

Use substring to get year, month, and day, if year greater than 11 add 19 to it if not add 20, to get year in format 2009, but this is your query just instead of string add your column name

```
 select CAST(
            CASE WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING('231280', 5, 2) AS INT) >11
                    THEN '19'+SUBSTRING('231280', 5, 2) 
                    else '20'+SUBSTRING('231280', 5, 2) 
                END 
        +'-'+SUBSTRING('231280', 3, 2)+'-'+SUBSTRING('231280', 1, 2) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use some substring footwork to convert your string to a known [date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  Here's an example converting the string to format 3, "British/French":

```
declare @YourTable table (YourColumn varchar(50))
insert @YourTable
          select '231280'
union all select '121280'
union all select '131185'

select  convert(datetime, substring(YourColumn,1,2) + '/' + 
    substring(YourColumn,3,2) + '/' + substring(YourColumn,5,2), 3)
from    @YourTable
```